# ipad sleep wake up event

Tags: ipad, uialertview

When the ipad goes to sleep i.e. the screen turns off, the user will turn it back on and the current application at the time  is still open. Is there a way to detect this event that the ipad has woken up from sleep?

I want to be show an UIAlert whenever it goes to sleep and wakes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` delegate method of the application delegate.